# Where to internationalize emails in a DDD application?

Tags: domain-driven-design, asp.net-core

I am building an application with ASP.NET Core 5.0 following DDD and the CQRS pattern. I internationalize on the presentational layer but when I send emails I send them in the application layer via an email sender service. This service doesnt know anything about internationalization because I have that capsuled on the presentational layer. So my question is how do I get internationalized emails in my application layer / email sender service, what is the best approach?

Edit:
In my current example I am trying to register a user and sending a verfication email. So I am dispatching a createUser command on the presentational layer (a Web Rest API) to my application layer. I create the user and use an email sender service. The content of the email has to be in the users language. I don't think that sending that email needs to be moved to the presentational layer.

If you need code excerpts let me know.

Comment: Without knowing anything else about your application, I'd say what you need to do is add localization to your email sender service.  How you do that is entirely up to you.  If you think you can commandeer your "presentation layer" to do that, by all means.  Otherwise, it's simply a matter of adding the necessary code to your email sender service.

Comment: Wording and formatting emails belongs in the presentation layer. The technical details of sending them are akin to the technical details of the web server that you use - not really relevant to your application design, just part of the infrastructure.

Comment: Why do you want the emails [localized](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-i18n) in your application layer? What's wrong with having "localization capsuled on the presentational layer"?

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner while I’d agree with this statement in some cases, it seems challengeable in general. What if the localized email content is business related (e.g. using product names in several languages, which means a multilingual business process and a domain model coping with multilingual data). What if the email content is defined  according to localized rules (e.g.with different thresholds depending on currency or country of the receiving party)?

Comment: Carlos, can you clarify if it’s about localization or internationalization, and the reason you think it does not belong to presentation layer? And can you tell more about  your email localization, e.g. is it mainly about translation or are there also other concerns?

Comment: @Christophe why? I'm not saying you can't. I'm asking what your motivation is. The presentation layer is typically about showing the same thing different ways. The application layer is typically about enforcing business rules. Are you unable to tease those apart? Where's the need here that's making you want to do this?

Comment: @candied_orange ah, sorry, I see now that your question was genuine. But reading it just after martin’s made it sound like a rhetoric question with the same position.

Comment: @Christophe I edited my question, I mean internationalization, not localization

Comment: @Carlos well done. I think the edit clarifies the ambiguities and questions in the comments. Final question: when you say “presentation layer” vs. “application layer” do you mean “front-end” vs “backend” ) ?

Comment: @Carlos thanks for the edit but I'm still not getting it. "The content of the email has to be in the users language. I don't think that sending that email needs to be moved to the presentational layer." Why isn't the users language something for the presentational layer to work out? What advantage do you get by moving that to the application layer? And why is the presentational layer issuing a createUser command, or any command, to the application layer? Again, not saying you can't do any of this. Just wondering how you got here. Cause this seems weird to me.

Comment: Hi @Carlos, "The content of the email has to be in the users language. I don't think that sending that email needs to be moved to the presentational layer." -> The email service does not need to know about the user, it only needs the language you want the email to be rendered on. It should not belong to your business domain only for this reason.

Comment: Without seeing a conceptual example (either code or a diagram), all this discussion about a presentation layer is kinda pointless.

Answer (score 1):

### Did you mean layers or tiers?

[**Tiers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) are independent processes or components that may potentially run on different processing nodes. The usual ones are presentation (front-end), application, and database.  They are often called "layer" because of the graphical representation, but it’s about **distribution of components**.

The internal structure may also be organized in **layers**,  according to some **split of responsibilities**. The naming of those layers depend on the authors but have similar names than the tiers (e.g. presentation, business/application, DAL).

This might create confusion, as internal layers do not necessarily correspond one-to-one with the distribution components.  We can agree that email localization cannot run on the presentation tier (front-end).

### How to solve it?

Your registration process needs to know the email address of the user for sending the mail.  But it also needs to know the language to use since the backend has other language parameters:

- You need to pass language information from the front-end (where it is known, either asking it from the user or taking it from the environment preferences) to the back-end (where it is needed). The best way to do this, is to pass it along with the email address to used.
- The email content is just standard text in the user's language (now know to the back-end) and does not involve any domain logic for composing it. It seems therefore that generating it, would still belong to the part of the presentation logic, even if running on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

At the higher layer, don’t send an email. Send a description of the contents of the email, and write a small layer that takes the description, translates it into English, and sends the email. That part is called “internationalisation”.

Now you get a good French speaker, a good German speaker etc. who can take your email description and write code to translate it into French, German etc. Obviously you would do a translation that is mostly table driven, so as far as possible the changes are just in some table.

(Currencies are interesting, because there is currency and user language. A German living in the UK might get a bill for an amount of British pound, but written in German. Translating “please pay £100” into “bitte zahlen Sie 100 Euros” would be fatal.